# Scala Code to connect to Spark and Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, cassandra

I have scala ( IntelliJ) running on my laptop. I also have Spark and Cassandra running on Machine A,B,C ( 3 node Cluster using DataStax, running in Analytics mode). 
I tried running Scala programs on Cluster, they are running fine. 
I need to create code and run using IntelliJ on my laptop. How do I connect and run. I know I am making mistake in the code. I used general words. I need to help in writing specific code? Example: Localhost is incorrect.

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

  object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark:master", "localhost")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val data = sc.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_table") 

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("APP_NAME")
    .setMaster("local")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "")
```

Use above code to connect to local spark and cassandra. If your cassandra cluster has authentication enabled then use username and password.

In case you want to connect to remote spark and cassandra cluster then replace localhost with cassandra host and in `setMaster` use `spark:\\SPARK_HOST`

Comment: How to set port number here ? I got add of table from oracle , how save specific columns in Cassandra ?

Comment: `spark.cassandra.connection.port` for specifying cassandra port... use `df.select(col1,col2,col3,...)`